# DRY link_to for current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to DRY this code with helper?

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "All images", images_path %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you saying you want call a method in the application helper?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`link_to_if`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) helper:

```
<%= link_to_if current_user, 'All Images', images_path %>
```